# Вывести массив массивов

Tags: c#, массивы

Добрый день. Нужно сделать так,чтобы, когда массив выводит значения,то рядом писалось какая строка выводится и её длина. Например : '11111 строка 0 длиною в 5'. Как бы сам не делал,постоянно это сообщение смешивается со всеми значениями массива.

```
        Random r = new Random();
        int x = r.Next(2, 8);

        int[][] myArray = new int [x][];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
        {
            myArray[i] = new int[i + x];
            for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].Length; j++)
            {
                myArray[i][j] = rnd.Next(0, 10);
                Console.Write(myArray[i][j]+" ");

            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Random r = new Random();
int x = r.Next(2, 8);

int[][] myArray = new int [x][];
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
{
    myArray[i] = new int[i + x];
    for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].Length; j++)
    {
        myArray[i][j] = rnd.Next(0, 10);
        Console.Write(myArray[i][j] + " ");

    }

    // добавлена только эта строка
    Console.Write($" line {i} with len {myArray[i].Length}");

    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Вывод:

```
6 0 4 5 0  line 0 with len 5
2 7 6 2 4 1  line 1 with len 6
2 6 2 5 0 7 2  line 2 with len 7
6 4 7 7 5 4 3 7  line 3 with len 8
4 1 0 9 0 4 0 7 6  line 4 with len 9
```